# Correlation between two matrices of different dimensions

Tags: r, correlation

I'm very new to R. I have two matrices of different dimensions, C (3 rows, 79 columns) and T(3 rows, 215 columns). I want my code to calculate the Spearman correlation between the first column of C and all the columns of T and return the maximum correlation with the indexes and of the columns. Then, the second column of C and all the columns of T and so on. In fact, I want to find the columns between two matrices which are most correlated. Hope it was clear.
What I did was a nested for loop, but the result is not what I search.

```
for (i in 1:79){
    for(j in 1:215){
        print(max(cor(C[,i],T[,j],method = c("spearman"))))
  }
}
```

Comment: HI, so basically you're doing spearman on 3vs3 vectors right? because with such low number of observation and spearman correlation coefficient, you will easily have 1 correlation, with only 3 values, it's kinda risky no?

Comment: And with only 3 values, you can only obtain : 0.5; -0.5; 1;-1 using spearman correlation. Isn't Pearson more adapted?

Comment: You are totally right, Pearson is much better for my case. But what is more important here is to have the right code, whether with Spearman or Pearson. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to loop over the columns.

```
x <- cor(C,T,method = c("spearman"))

out <- data.frame(MaxCorr = apply(x,1,max), T_ColIndex=apply(x,1,which.max),C_ColIndex=1:nrow(x))

head(out)
```

gives,

```
  MaxCorr T_ColIndex C_ColIndex
1       1          8          1
2       1          1          2
3       1          2          3
4       1          1          4
5       1         11          5
6       1          4          6
```

**Fake Data:**

```
C <- matrix(rnorm(3*79),nrow=3)
T <- matrix(rnorm(3*215),nrow=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the function below can solve the problem.

```
pairwise_cor <- function(x, y, method = "spearman"){
  ix <- seq_len(ncol(x))
  iy <- seq_len(ncol(y))
  t(sapply(ix, function(i){
    m <- sapply(iy, function(j) cor(x[,i], y[,j], method = method))
    setNames(c(i, which.max(m), max(m)), c("col_x", "col_y", "max"))
  }))
}

set.seed(2021)
C <- matrix(rnorm(3*5), nrow=3)
T <- matrix(rnorm(3*7), nrow=3)

pairwise_cor(C, T)
#     col_x col_y max
#[1,]     1     1 1.0
#[2,]     2     2 1.0
#[3,]     3     2 1.0
#[4,]     4     3 0.5
#[5,]     5     5 1.0
```